# Decoding HTML entities in Emacs/Elisp

Tags: html, emacs, encoding, elisp

Some online websites like to encode all their text through HTML entities, so instead of seeing a text
like

```
So I'm looking
```

You get something like:

```
&#83;&#111;&#32;&#73;&#39;&#109;&#32;&#108;&#111;&#111;&#107;&#105;&#110;&#103;&#32;
```

I was wondering if there's a built in way to translate the encoded text to regular text using any
Emacs built-ins or if I should declare my map of strings ("&83" => "S"...) and manually decode it using
a map.

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: BTW: Those are NOT HTML entities, but Unicode entities - which is different. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references#Character_reference_overview

Answer (score 2):

I wrote this function to deal with non-numeric unicode entities, in case anybody needs.

```
(defun html-entities-to-unicode (string)
  (let* ((plist '(Aacute "Á" aacute "á" Acirc "Â" acirc "â" acute "´" AElig "Æ" aelig "æ" Agrave "À" agrave "à" alefsym "ℵ" Alpha "Α" alpha "α" amp "&" and "∧" ang "∠" apos "'" aring "å" Aring "Å" asymp "≈" atilde "ã" Atilde "Ã" auml "ä" Auml "Ä" bdquo "„" Beta "Β" beta "β" brvbar "¦" bull "•" cap "∩" ccedil "ç" Ccedil "Ç" cedil "¸" cent "¢" Chi "Χ" chi "χ" circ "ˆ" clubs "♣" cong "≅" copy "©" crarr "↵" cup "∪" curren "¤" Dagger "‡" dagger "†" darr "↓" dArr "⇓" deg "°" Delta "Δ" delta "δ" diams "♦" divide "÷" eacute "é" Eacute "É" ecirc "ê" Ecirc "Ê" egrave "è" Egrave "È" empty "∅" emsp " " ensp " " Epsilon "Ε" epsilon "ε" equiv "≡" Eta "Η" eta "η" eth "ð" ETH "Ð" euml "ë" Euml "Ë" euro "€" exist "∃" fnof "ƒ" forall "∀" frac12 "½" frac14 "¼" frac34 "¾" frasl "⁄" Gamma "Γ" gamma "γ" ge "≥" gt ">" harr "↔" hArr "⇔" hearts "♥" hellip "…" iacute "í" Iacute "Í" icirc "î" Icirc "Î" iexcl "¡" igrave "ì" Igrave "Ì" image "ℑ" infin "∞" int "∫" Iota "Ι" iota "ι" iquest "¿" isin "∈" iuml "ï" Iuml "Ï" Kappa "Κ" kappa "κ" Lambda "Λ" lambda "λ" lang "〈" laquo "«" larr "←" lArr "⇐" lceil "⌈" ldquo "“" le "≤" lfloor "⌊" lowast "∗" loz "◊" lrm "" lsaquo "‹" lsquo "‘" lt "<" macr "¯" mdash "—" micro "µ" middot "·" minus "−" Mu "Μ" mu "μ" nabla "∇" nbsp "" ndash "–" ne "≠" ni "∋" not "¬" notin "∉" nsub "⊄" ntilde "ñ" Ntilde "Ñ" Nu "Ν" nu "ν" oacute "ó" Oacute "Ó" ocirc "ô" Ocirc "Ô" OElig "Œ" oelig "œ" ograve "ò" Ograve "Ò" oline "‾" omega "ω" Omega "Ω" Omicron "Ο" omicron "ο" oplus "⊕" or "∨" ordf "ª" ordm "º" oslash "ø" Oslash "Ø" otilde "õ" Otilde "Õ" otimes "⊗" ouml "ö" Ouml "Ö" para "¶" part "∂" permil "‰" perp "⊥" Phi "Φ" phi "φ" Pi "Π" pi "π" piv "ϖ" plusmn "±" pound "£" Prime "″" prime "′" prod "∏" prop "∝" Psi "Ψ" psi "ψ" quot "\"" radic "√" rang "〉" raquo "»" rarr "→" rArr "⇒" rceil "⌉" rdquo "”" real "ℜ" reg "®" rfloor "⌋" Rho "Ρ" rho "ρ" rlm "" rsaquo "›" rsquo "’" sbquo "‚" scaron "š" Scaron "Š" sdot "⋅" sect "§" shy "" Sigma "Σ" sigma "σ" sigmaf "ς" sim "∼" spades "♠" sub "⊂" sube "⊆" sum "∑" sup "⊃" sup1 "¹" sup2 "²" sup3 "³" supe "⊇" szlig "ß" Tau "Τ" tau "τ" there4 "∴" Theta "Θ" theta "θ" thetasym "ϑ" thinsp " " thorn "þ" THORN "Þ" tilde "˜" times "×" trade "™" uacute "ú" Uacute "Ú" uarr "↑" uArr "⇑" ucirc "û" Ucirc "Û" ugrave "ù" Ugrave "Ù" uml "¨" upsih "ϒ" Upsilon "Υ" upsilon "υ" uuml "ü" Uuml "Ü" weierp "℘" Xi "Ξ" xi "ξ" yacute "ý" Yacute "Ý" yen "¥" yuml "ÿ" Yuml "Ÿ" Zeta "Ζ" zeta "ζ" zwj "" zwnj ""))
         (get-function (lambda (s) (or (plist-get plist (intern (substring s 1 -1))) s))))
    (replace-regexp-in-string "&[^; ]*;" get-function string)))
```

Answer (score 1):

I wrote the following, which does what you need, @federico-builes. (I needed the same thing.)

```
(defun ajs-decimal-escapes-to-unicode (start end)
  "Convert escapes like '&#955;' to Unicode like 'λ'.
Operates on the active region or the whole buffer."
  (interactive (list (point) (mark)))
  (or (use-region-p)
      (setq start (point-min) end (point-max)))
  (insert (replace-regexp-in-string
           "&#[0-9]*;"
           (lambda (match)
             (format "%c" (string-to-number (substring match 2 -1))))
           (filter-buffer-substring start end t))))
```

@konr's response was helpful - thanks! I've also been enjoying [An Introduction to Programming in Emacs Lisp](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_mono/eintr.html). This is the first Lisp I've written that might be useful. I'd appreciate feedback, even on things like whitespace; thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if there is a built in function, but this small function can do the job:

```
(defun my-insert-encode-entities-string (str)
  (mapconcat
   (lambda (char) (format "&#%d;" char))
   (string-to-list str)
   ""))
```

If you only wish to encode HTML entities, use `url-insert-entities-in-string` instead.

Comment: The function is wrong since you don't want to format as %d, you want to get a %d and format it as a char.

Comment: @Federico: I'm not sure if I can see your point. Calling `(my-insert-encode-entities-string "So I'm looking")` returns exactly the same result you provided. Variable `char` holds the current character represented as a integer so in this particular case I think it's no matter whether using `%s` or `%d`.

Comment: @Török: There was a little misunderstanding, as you can see in the question I was looking for "...a built in way to translate the encoded text to regular text". Your solution converts regular to encoded text :)

I wrote this http://gist.github.com/222709 to fix it but it's obviously not as clean as your original proposal.